# What do these sentences mean with "to do something"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, to-infinitive

> 1. My hands are wet to write.
> 2. He is doing his homework to play.
> 3. I have some projects to do to watch movies right now.

Do these sentences mean that:

> "the subject is in a condition(wet) or doing something(homework/project) due to which they are not able to do something else(write/play/watch movies)"

Or do they mean that:

> "the subject is in a condition(wet) or doing something(homework/project) so that they could do the other thing(write/play/watch movies)

Answer (score 2):

These look awkward.  I suppose the intended meaning is

> My hands are wet in order for me to write.  (perhaps you have made your hands wet so you can write with water using your wet finger?)

It's a very odd thing to describe.  Usually, if you are writing you want dry hands (or the ink might smudge)

You can say

> My hands are too wet to write.

The adverb "too" makes all the difference, because it means that you cannot write.

The others are also not understandable. The literal meaning is

> He is doing his homework in order that he can play.

But if he is doing homework, then he can't play! This makes it very hard to understand. You could say

> He is doing his homework to get good mark in the test.

But perhaps you meant one of:

> He's doing homework now to be able to play later.

or

> He's doing homework so he can't play.

And likewise

> I have some projects to do, so I can't watch movies right now.

As they stand, your examples don't make much sense to me.